# Error reference to 'distance' is ambiguous

Tags: c++, reference, c++17, friend-function, ambiguous-call

I cannot figure out why I am getting the error "`reference to 'distance' is ambiguous`".
I have passed class object as an argument in friend function.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class distance {
    int meters = 0;
public:
    distance() {}
    void displaydata() {
        cout << "Meters Value:" << meters;
    }
    //Prototype
    friend void addvalue(distance &d);
};

void addvalue(distance &d) {
    d.meters += 5;
}

int main() {
    distance d1; // meters = 0
    d1.displaydata(); // 0
    // The friend function call
    addvalue(d1); // pass by reference
    d1.displaydata();
}
```

Comment: It's because you are `using namespace std;`. Don't to that, [it's a bad practice to do so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: There already is a `std::distance` function.  Since you are including all `std` symbols into your namespace, the compiler can get confused as to which `distance` symbol you are referring to.  Try prefixing *your* `distance` with `::` as in `::distance d1;`

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `using namespace std;` and change `cout` to `std::cout`, then your code compiles w/o error.

Discovering the source of the ambiguity is left as [an exercise to the reader](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance)

Comment: Already tried that but didn't workedd out for me.

Comment: but I have found a fix all I had to do is to just change "distance" to "Distance" and the ambiguity was fixed